# Cypress: extracting a portion of a string

Tags: string, split, cypress

I would appreciate some help. I am getting this text from a span: ***| **1-25 / 10.000 +++***** However, I would need to extract just 10.000
How could I split this string? Thank you very much in advance

```
   cy.get('.page-number > span')
           .then(($total) => {
              const total = $total.text();
              cy.log(total);
    })
```

Comment: are you trying to do an assertion (that max is `10.000`), or is it important to get the variable and log it (use `.then()`)?

Comment: Yes, I will need to get the number to do an operation with expect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to assert that the `10.000` is in there, you could do a simple assertion like

```js
cy.get(`.page-number > span`).contains('10.000').should("exist");
// or
cy.get(`.page-number > span`).contains('1-25 / 10.000').should("exist");
```

or if you want to make sure it's at the end of the string, using regex...

```js
cy.get(`.page-number > span`).contains(/10\.000$/gmi).should("exist");
```

I fund using the simpler `contains().should()` assertions easier.

However if you want make the assertion within the promise, here are some things to keep in mind

- the element passed from `cy.get()` will be a jQuery array. So running `.text()` on an Array will not work. You can specify using `.eq(0)` either inside or outside the promise, and once you have that text, you can do a regEx to retrieve value.
- if you are using `cy.get().then`, it will give you the data at-the-time-of-operation. That is, it will not wait for the internal assertion to match. So if you are loading dynamic data, you might find that the text is not popupated yet

```js
cy.get(".page-number > span").then(($total) => {
  const total = $total.eq(0).text(); // eq(0) inside promise
  cy.log(total.match(/([\d\.]*)$/gmi)[0]);
});

cy.get(".page-number > span")
  .eq(0) // eq(0) outside promise
  .then(($total) => {
    const total = $total.text();
    cy.log(total.match(/([\d\.]*)$/gmi)[0]);
  });
});
```

you can adjust the regex to more precisely match your needs. This one gets the last set of numbers (`/d`) or (`[]`) periods (`./`) before the end of the string (`$`). your html might include an extra space that's not visible, so you can add an optional space character (`/s?`): `/([\d\.]*)\s?$/gmi`